# Scroll problems with too many elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am having problems with scrolling on a project I am working on. I have a large number of images in the DOM which I think is causing the scrolling to be slow and making the page judder.

I dont want to remove any of these images from the DOM, I would like to know if there is a way that I can replace these images with a temporary placeholder and then only render the correct image as soon as the element scrolls into view.

Comment: you could try intersectionObserver API: https://corydowdy.com/blog/lazy-loading-images-with-intersection-observer

Comment: https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear it's not javascript but its useful

Comment: note that if the problem comes from the number of images itself, adding placeholders to every of them with Javascript events will probably not solve the problem, you may have to group these in sections that will show/hide, instead of each image

Comment: @Kaddath Well you can have placeholders generated by css and then load an image once it scrolls into view + a bit of delay.

Comment: @redFur i understand that perfectly, what i say is that if his scrolling problems come from too many elements in the DOM, having a javascript event on all these elements without reducing the number should cause equivalent problems too. But he can reduce that by grouping them in sections. Note that the image loading is not the problem the OP is having, but scrolling (display) issues, so the images are all loaded already when his problem occurs, delay the loading won't fix the scrolling

Comment: Hard to tell without any code. Have your several elements some `:hover` styles (that can kill scroll performance) ?